# C++ Compare 2 dates and check the minutes difference

Tags: c++, json, datetime, jsoncpp

Here's the thing:

A datetime access is created with C# using `DateTime.Now`. This datetime is passed through JSON to a C++ method. I'm using JsonCpp to handle the Json data, but I'm not sure how to handle when the data is a datetime.

I want to compare this datetime that I received with the actual datetime and check the minutes difference between this two (if the difference is on a interval that was defined).

If I convert the Json datetime to a string using JsonCpp I have this format:

```
2015-06-08T11:17:23.746389-03:00
```

So what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
var d1 = oldAccess["Date"].ToString(); //Json datetime converted to a string
var d2 = actualAccess["Date"].ToString()
if((d2 - d1) < 20) { //Difference between the two dates needs to be less than 20 minutes
    return true;
} else return false;
```

I'm new in C++, even looking for I don't discovered how to do this.

Comment: The question is not very clear do you need to convert a string into a DateTime object in C# ?

Comment: @Marco, the datetime was created in C#, passed through Json in this format: `2015-06-08T11:17:23.746389-03:00`, than I need to convert and compare in C++

Comment: I think you should consider using something like Boost.Date_Time to parse the string representing the timestamp and then doing the required comparison.

Comment: Are you using plain c++ (gcc) or you have some library like boost or Qt and which compiler?

Comment: No library, I'm looking Boost now how @dschulz suggests. I'm compiling with Visual Studio.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, despite the tag, this has nothing to do with JSON or with JsonCPP?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tagged JSON and JsonCPP because the data were in JSON format and I was using JsonCPP to handling this data. So, I expected that someone could help me with this maybe using JsonCPP own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got it. Not the best way neither the pretty one, but it works since I know that the two dates were set on the same server and always comes in the same format `\"2015-01-01T23:40:00.000000-03:00\"`

Here's what I did:

```
int convertToInt(std::string number_str){
    int number;
    std::istringstream ss(number_str);
    ss.imbue(std::locale::classic());
    ss >> number;
    return number;
}

time_t convertDatetime(std::string date_str) {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm date;
    int year, month, day, hour, min, sec;

    date_str.erase(std::remove_if(date_str.begin(), date_str.end(), isspace), date_str.end());

    year = convertToInt(date_str.substr(1, 4));
    month = convertToInt(date_str.substr(6, 2));
    day = convertToInt(date_str.substr(9, 2));
    hour = convertToInt(date_str.substr(12, 2));
    min = convertToInt(date_str.substr(15, 2));
    sec = convertToInt(date_str.substr(18, 2));

    time(&rawtime);
    localtime_s(&date, &rawtime);
    date.tm_year = year - 1900;
    date.tm_mon = month - 1;
    date.tm_mday = day;
    date.tm_hour = hour;
    date.tm_min = min;
    date.tm_sec = sec;

    return mktime(&date);
}

bool isValidIntervalDatetime(std::string actualDatetime_str, std::string oldDatetime_str, int maxMinutesInterval) {
    double maxSecondsInterval = 60 * maxMinutesInterval;
    time_t actualDatetime = convertDatetime(actualDatetime_str);
    time_t oldDatetime = convertDatetime(oldDatetime_str);

    double secondsDiff = difftime(actualDatetime, oldDatetime);

    return secondsDiff <= maxSecondsInterval;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto maxMinutesInterval = 20;
    auto actuaDatetime = JsonConverter::toString(actualAccess["Date"]); // \"2015-01-02T00:00:00.000000-03:00\"
    auto oldDatetime = JsonConverter::toString(oldAccess["Date"]); // \"2015-01-01T23:40:00.000000-03:00\"

    if (isValidIntervalDatetime(actuaDatetime, oldDatetime, maxMinutesInterval){
        //do something
    }
}
```